# Composer not respecting constraint defined in composer.json

Tags: composer

I have a build, with the following constraint on `drupal/core`, for some reason the constraint is not respected.

Upon running composer install this comes up:

```
 - Downloading drupal/core (9.5.0-rc1)
```

Composer show -i drupal/core:

```
name     : drupal/core
descrip. : Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.
keywords :
versions : * 9.5.0-rc1
```

I seriously would prefer having stable drupal/core.  I am able to "force the universe" by doing  `composer require drupal/core --update-with-dependencies`, and committing the generated .lock file.

Why, *composer*, why?!?

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "acme/drupal",
    "description": "Acquia-compatible Drupal application based on the Drupal Recommended Project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Acquia Engineering",
            "homepage": "https://www.acquia.com",
            "role": "Maintainer"
        }
    ],
    "repositories": {
        "asset-packagist": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        },
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "acquia/acquia-cms-starterkit": "^1",
        "acquia/blt": "^13.5",
        "acquia/drupal-environment-detector": "^1",
        "acquia/http-hmac-php": "6.0.0",
        "acquia/memcache-settings": "^1",
        "composer/installers": "^2.1",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
        "drupal/address": "^1.11",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.1",
        "drupal/coffee": "^1.2",
        "drupal/config_ignore": "^2.3",
        "drupal/config_readonly": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/config_split": "^1.9",
        "drupal/core": "~9.4",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "~9.4",
        "drupal/drimage": "^2.0",
        "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.8",
        "drupal/entity_clone": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.2",
        "drupal/focal_point": "^1.5",
        "drupal/fpa": "^3.0",
        "drupal/gin": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/insert": "^1.0",
        "drupal/link_attributes": "^1.11",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^3.2",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.15",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.11",
        "drupal/scheduler": "^1.4",
        "drupal/seckit": "^2.0",
        "drupal/section_library": "^1.0",
        "drupal/section_library_reusable": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/shield": "^1.6",
        "drupal/twig_tweak": "^3.1",
        "drupal/upgrade_status": "^3.13",
        "drupal/webprofiler": "^9.0",
        "drush/drush": "^10.6 || ^11",
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^1.1 || ^2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "acquia/blt-phpcs": "^1.0",
        "acquia/coding-standards": "^1.0.0",
        "behat/behat": "^3.11",
        "behat/mink": "^1.10",
        "drupal/devel": "^4.1",
        "drupal/drupal-extension": "^4.2",
        "drupal/twig_vardumper": "^3.0",
        "mglaman/phpstan-drupal": "^1.1",
        "phpspec/prophecy-phpunit": "^2.0",
        "phpstan/extension-installer": "^1.1",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.6",
        "phpstan/phpstan-deprecation-rules": "^1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.6"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "ergebnis/composer-normalize": true,
            "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": true,
            "phpstan/extension-installer": true,
            "acquia/blt": true,
            "acquia/blt-phpcs": true,
            "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true
        },
        "platform": {
            "php": "8.1"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "allowed-packages": [
                "acquia/acquia_cms"
            ],
            "file-mapping": {
                "[profile-root]/.editorconfig": false,
                "[profile-root]/.gitattributes": false,
                "[profile-root]/.travis.yml": false,
                "[profile-root]/acquia-pipelines.yml": false,
                "[web-root]/sites/default/default.services.yml": {
                    "mode": "replace",
                    "overwrite": false,
                    "path": "docroot/core/assets/scaffold/files/default.services.yml"
                },
                "[web-root]/sites/default/default.settings.php": {
                    "mode": "replace",
                    "overwrite": false,
                    "path": "docroot/core/assets/scaffold/files/default.settings.php"
                }
            },
            "gitignore": true,
            "locations": {
                "profile-root": "docroot/profiles/contrib/acquia_cms",
                "web-root": "docroot/"
            }
        },
        "enable-patching": true,
        "installer-paths": {
            "docroot/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "docroot/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library",
                "type:bower-asset",
                "type:npm-asset"
            ],
            "docroot/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "docroot/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "docroot/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "docroot/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "docroot/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ]
        },
        "installer-types": [
            "bower-asset",
            "npm-asset"
        ],
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "patches": {
            "drupal/core": {
                "Break long text strings in layout edit": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-12-22/3016507-50.patch",
                "Improve StringItem::generateSampleValue()": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-06-24/3091478-15.patch",
                "Not all form elements can't use in vertical_tabs": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-01-02/3122920_group_patch_5.patch",
                "PHP message: Error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null (Layout Builder)": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-08-05/3049332-inline-35.patch",
                "Stream wrapper reference in JS library causes error in _locale_parse_js_file()": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-05-08/2735717-28.patch",
                "New non translatable field on translatable content throws error": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-02-10/3025039_42.patch"
            },
            "drupal/section_library": {
                "#3228163: Add create or update logic.": "https://git.drupalcode.org/project/section_library/-/merge_requests/3.patch"
            }
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "acms:install": [
            "./vendor/bin/acms acms:install"
        ],
        "nuke": [
            "rm -rf docroot vendor composer.lock"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You have tilde constraints and “minimum-stability": "dev".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about Composer usage, and not truly specific to Drupal. I understand if others disagree.

Comment: @cilefen Thanks mate, I totally understand your point but this is a grey area... as the installation and setup of the app requires knowledge of this component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set `"minimum-stability": "stable"`.
2. Remove `drupal/core` from `composer.json` requirements section. It is superfluous.
3. `composer require drupal/core-recommended:^9.4 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^9.4 -W`.

Once you do that you have more work to do because of things that don't make sense, like `drupal/insert 1.0.0 requires drupal/core ^8`. If that is removed you have:

```
 Root composer.json requires drupal/gin ^3.0@beta -> satisfiable by drupal/gin[3.0.0-beta1, ..., 3.0.0-beta5].
    - drupal/gin[3.0.0-beta1, ..., 3.0.0-beta5] require drupal/gin_toolbar ^1.0@beta -> found drupal/gin_toolbar[dev-1.x, 1.0.0-alpha1, ..., 1.x-dev (alias of dev-1.x)] but it does not match your minimum-stability.
```

When that happens you have to specify dev versions of the dependencies explicitly.